# How to modify certain values in a list that is inside a list (in R)

Tags: r, list

I have a list that consists of several lists that have certain structure: character, numeric sequence, and character:

```
myList <- list(list("name1", c(2000,2001,2002), "suffix1"),
               list("name2", c(2000,2001,2002), "suffix2"),
               list("name3", c(2000,2001,2002), "suffix3")
               )
```

I want to modify the list so that the sequence is limited to certain maximum value, say 2001, in some of the lower nest lists, say the first two:

```
myListModified <- list(list("name1", c(2000,2001), "suffix1"),
                       list("name2", c(2000,2001), "suffix2"),
                       list("name3", c(2000,2001,2002), "suffix3")
                       )
```

I've tried a few ways to subset first the upper nest list and then the elements in lower nest lists but that's not as straightforward as I thought. Perhaps there's some completely different way to tackle this?

Comment: Do you need a loop or is `L  <- myList; L[[1]][[2]] <- L[[1]][[2]][1:2]; L[[2]][[2]] <- L[[2]][[2]][1:2]` sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop over the first two `list` elements, check if the element is numeric, then get the `intersect` of the values with the 2001:2002 or else return the object.

```
myList[1:2] <- lapply(myList[1:2], function(x) 
  lapply(x, function(y) if(is.numeric(y)) intersect(y, 2001:2002) else y))
```

Answer (score 3):

> Perhaps there's some completely different way to tackle this?

Here's one suggestion:

```
library(data.table)
DT = rbindlist(rapply(myList, function(x) if (length(x)>1) list(x) else x, how="replace"))
setnames(DT,c("name","y","s"))
#     name              y       s
# 1: name1 2000,2001,2002 suffix1
# 2: name2 2000,2001,2002 suffix2
# 3: name3 2000,2001,2002 suffix3

DT[1:2, y := lapply(y, function(yy) yy[yy <= 2001] )]
#     name              y       s
# 1: name1      2000,2001 suffix1
# 2: name2      2000,2001 suffix2
# 3: name3 2000,2001,2002 suffix3
```

This works like `DT[i,j]` where `i` is filtering rows and `j` is replacing the `y` column.

---

Answer (score 0):

A two step procedure similar to the answer from akrun:

```
inds <- lapply(myList, function(x) which(x[[2]] %in% 2002:2003)) 
myList2 <- lapply(1:length(myList), function(x) list(myList[[x]][[1]],
                                                     myList[[x]][[2]][-inds[[x]]],
                                                     myList[[x]][[3]]))
```

1. We loop over the main list, and find the indices of unwanted
   elements in the vector that is the second item of each nested list
2. We reconstruct the main list while removing unwanted elements in the
       second item of each nested list